# ng-click or ng-href in table row repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

this is the code in the html page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="res in result" ng-click='go()'>

    <td>{{res.value1}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value2}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value3}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value4}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value5}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value6}}</td>

</tr>
```

and this is the code in .js file:

```
$scope.go = function () {
    $scope.go = function (url) {
        $location.path(url);
    }
}
```

my principal problem is that i need to use the entire row like a link, something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="bla bla bla" href="url">
```

but neither ng-href or the ng-click works, what am i doing wrong?

ok, i have forget the parenthesis, but the principal problem still remain, is it possible to use href with the tr? and if the answer is yes, how?

i have edit the code to precise what my really problem is, if i use the ng-click like an href i can't use a code like that

```
go('/something/{{res.value1}}
```

my goal is to pass an url that change in base at the row that i click.

Comment: It should work. Have you check your console? There should be some error

Comment: the console didn't print anything, it's like i don't even click on the row, i cant't really understand why.

Comment: @mautrok -- see my answer below, simple syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `()`

```
ng-click="go()"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed something silly. Make sure you have bound `ng-controller` in `HTML`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="res in result" ng-click='go()'>
            <td>{{res.value1}}</td>
            <td>{{res.value2}}</td>
            <td>{{res.value3}}</td>
            <td>{{res.value4}}</td>
            <td>{{res.value5}}</td>
            <td>{{res.value6}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    // Your json will be here
    $scope.result = [
        {value1:"1",value2:"2",value3:"3"},
        {value1:"5",value2:"6",value3:"7"},
        {value1:"4",value2:"9",value3:"8"}
        ];

    $scope.go = function(){
        console.log("function called!!!");
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/60/)**</kbd>